# MySQL - Subtrack week from YearWeek column correctly

Tags: mysql, date, week-number

I have a calendar table in MySQL that maintains a column having YEARWEEK value (eg: 202230, 202301). When I am trying to substract one week from this column (which is integer type), for boundary cases like 202301, it is giving incorrect result.

```
Eg: 202230 - 1 = 202229
Eg: 202301 - 1 = 202301 which is incorrect. Correct value should be 202252.
```

I have tried to do cast it into string and do substring operations however few years have 53 weeks.

What is the correct way I can achieve this?

Comment: Convert your YEARWEEK value to definite date, substract 7 days, convert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date of a specific day, for example Sunday, of that yearweek value with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE('202301 Sunday', '%X%V %W')
```

and subtract 1 week:

```
STR_TO_DATE('202301 Sunday', '%X%V %W') - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

and the above date can be used to get the yearweek that you want:

```
YEARWEEK(STR_TO_DATE('202301 Sunday', '%X%V %W') - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

In the case of your calendar table you can do it like this:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(
         STR_TO_DATE(
          CONCAT(year_week_col, ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
       ) AS result
FROM calendar;
```

Change `calendar` and `year_week_col` to the names of the table and the column respectively.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b326f67b9760a0e8af9b30630a1b21c).

Answer (score 0):

Utilising what you have perhaps a sub query to find the most recent prior to current

```
with cte as
(
select yearweek(dte) yw, count(*) 
from dates 
where dte between'2021-12-15' and '2022-01-15'
group by yearweek(dte)
)
select *,(select yw from cte cte1 where cte1.yw < cte.yw order by cte1.yw desc limit 1) prevyw
from cte
;

+--------+----------+--------+
| yw     | count(*) | prevyw |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 202150 |        4 |   NULL |
| 202151 |        7 | 202150 |
| 202152 |        7 | 202151 |
| 202201 |        7 | 202152 |
| 202202 |        7 | 202201 |
+--------+----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.006 sec)
```